# Breakpoints not working, PhpStorm on MAC, PHP running on Ubuntu server

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I have an Ubuntu server running Apache and PHP7, with Xdebug installed and confirmed in the phpinfo():

```
          xdebug
xdebug support    enabled
Version           2.6.0
IDE Key           PHPSTORM
```

My PhpStorm is running on a Mac, a different machine. The webserver is running as it should. If I debug a PHP script from PhpStorm debugging also works fine. But if I add a breakpoint to my code in PhpStorm and run the PHP from a web browser the debugger doesn't seem to do anything. My code just executes. PhpStorm doesn't start debugging at my set breakpoint.

If I purposely add an error to my PHP code I can see by the output that Xdebug is doing something on the server, the error is presented in the xdebug-error table.

In the correct PHP.ini on the Ubuntu server I set the correct settings:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.130
```

So:

- PhpStorm is listening for PHP Debug connections, or at least the "listen for debug connections" is enabled
- Both are configures to listen/talk to port 9000
- CLI interpreter is set correctly to the remote Ubuntu server
- Path mapping is correct (in my case: `/volumes/internet` -> `/var/www`)
- [Edit] Port scan on 9000 shows cslistener when PhpStorm is listening, when turned off there's nothing there

I would love to get my breakpoints working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shut down PhpStorm and check if anything is running on port 9000. If there's anything (like php-fpm) - change XDebug port to 9001.

Comment: @Ástþór, thanks. Tried that, but it seems port 9000 isn't used by anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xdebug.remote_host` should not be set to the IP of the machine XDebug is running on, it should be set to the machine you're running PHPStorm on!

Another option is to set `xdebug.remote_connect_back` to `true`. When this is enabled the `xdebug.remote_host` setting is ignored and Xdebug will try to connect to the client that made the HTTP request. It checks the `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variables to find out which IP address to use. ([See the XDEBUG manual](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings))